# Ember JS make a GET request to an API

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I want to make a `GET` request to an api and the request in the server side looks like below, using AJAX

```
http://localhost:8000/api/?email=test@test.com
```

In other words, instead, instead of populating data to our ember model using the command, `return this.store.query('testmodel',{ email: test@test.com })`, I need replace this by a AJAX call in the `ember controller`

Please Help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can set up ajax as an ember service you can inject to your controller.

install the [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) service:

```
ember install ember-ajax
```

Restart your server. Then in your controller you can inject the service:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    sendRequest() {
      return this.get('ajax').request('/api', {
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
          email: 'test@test.com'
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

With that done, just add a button that will fire the action or call the action when you need it in the controller.